# Twilio call automatically cuts after 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I have been facing this problem for 1 week now which stands as when the call is generated it automatically cuts after 2 minutes of recording of the call . Here is the TwiML

```
<Response>
<Say voice="woman" language="en">Hii Welcome to our App</Say>
<Record timeout="10" />
</Response>
```

And this is the code :

```
client.calls.create(
    {
      url: "http://19f68022.ngrok.io/bot.xml",
      to: '+*******',
      from: '+*******',
    },
    function (err, call) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(call);
      }
    }
  );
```

Please Help Guys this is really a severe issue with twilio
Note :  Using a twilio Trail account

Comment: If it is a severe issue with twilio, what do their developers have to say about it? Have you looked at their issue tracker / bug reports and subscribed to this issue? Usually when there is an issue with a service, the first place to go to address that issue is the service...

Comment: i already tried contacting developers and no response from them

Comment: @karanroy  please post the solution also.I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the logs of your twilio number - https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/calls/logs/.
You might get the reason of the call failure over there.

And your TWIML suggests the recording timeout of 10 seconds. You should increase it make the length of the recording longer. If you want to continue the call after the recording you need to specify an *action* or *transcribeCallback* url which may be your code or a twilio function.

```
<Response>
<Say voice="woman" language="en">Hii Welcome to our App</Say>
<Record timeout="10" transcribe="true" action="handler.js"/>
</Response>
```

or

```
<Response>
<Say voice="woman" language="en">Hii Welcome to our App</Say>
<Record timeout="10" transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="handler.js"/>
</Response>
```

Also, I might be able to provide a better response if you post additional info(usecase or requirement).

Comment: @karanroy please post the solution also.I am facing the same issue.

Comment: <Response>
  <Say loop="1">Record Your message.</Say>
  <Record action="http://example.com/api/voice/record.xml" maxLength="3600" timeout="50"/>
</Response>